# I cant pick the value of input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.submit__form').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = '.' + $(this).data('id');
    var person__name = $('#person__name').val();
    var person__email = $('#person__email').val();
    var booking__participants = $('#booking__participants').val();

    alert(person__email || 'none');

    // if (person__email === '' || person__name === '' || booking__participants === '') {
    //  alert('Preencha os campos obrigatórios.');
    // } else {
    //  $(id).submit();
    // }
});
```

I don't know why, but i can't pick the value of the person__name and person__email, the most strange part is that i can pick the value in the console on the browser... someone knows what could be causing this?

This is not a problem of html the 2 inputs fields have the id person__name and person__email.

The code is in a external file, and i am calling that in the bottom of my html.

HTML:

```
<form>

<input id="person__name" name="person.name" type="text" />
<input id="person__email" name="person.email" type="email" />


<a class="submit__form">Submit</a> 
</form>
```

I cant use the submit input.

UPDATE:

The scripts in the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/0.9.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headroom/0.6.0/headroom.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.5/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/client/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Inside the main script:

```
(function() {
 //code

})();
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example

Comment: Without posting the html, we can't tell if your jquery selectors are correct

Comment: `class="submit__form` - `"`

Comment: ops, sorry.. this was a typo in the question.. in the code is closed..

Comment: I never understand why people don't paste the actual code rather than something with typos in it...

Comment: in the past i paste the whole code, but some guy said that is better use examples code.

Comment: OK, so take your code, trim it down, *check it still works*, then paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alert the name, make sure you use the name in the jQuery

```
alert(person__name || 'none');
// Not:
alert(person__email || 'none');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/376fLujs/3/

Also, make sure your script is included properly. Include the jQuery before your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="local.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

1. add: console.log("working"); as the very first line of your script
2. open the chrome console / Firebug and refresh your page.
3. if you don't see "working" in the console, your javascript is not included properly.

Edit: based on your comments again.  If you have multiple forms, re-using the same ID, it will not work.  Always keep IDs unique.  Since your link is inside of the form like your input, you could do this:

```
var person__email = $(this).parent().find("input[name='person.email']").val();
// DRX points out that escaping may be necessary:
var person__name = $(this).parent().find("input[name='person\\.name']").val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/376fLujs/4/

Comment: here the alert is 'none'.

Comment: The jQuery is alerting the email, not the name.  Edit: updated the answer to reflect your question in the comment.

Comment: sorry, didn't notes that haha.. i am using a script tag in the bottom of my page, if i try alert the email will work, the problem is the name..

Comment: The name is working in the fiddle I posted (http://jsfiddle.net/376fLujs/3/).  Can you put the line of code you're using to include your script into your question?

Comment: i figure out Jon, i have 4 forms with the same ids, just the first one will work , obvius.

Comment: That's correct: you should never use duplicate IDs.  Duplicate class is fine, but not IDs.

Comment: yes, i know haha.. the problem is that i'm using a looping to create this forms, and i didn't note the problem.. thanks anyway! :D

Comment: OK.  Check my updated post how you could get the value you're looking for from the correct form.

Comment: It works fine without the escape (http://jsfiddle.net/376fLujs/4/), and makes for more legible code.  Does it not work without the escape in your project?

Comment: nop.. if i try will broke the code cause will not recognize

Answer (score 0):

I would say try using this for your event handling:

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit__form', function(e) {
    //code here
});
```

The reason it might not be working is because the element might not yet be created when the script loads. This should take care of that issue.

Comment: @DRX interesting. Have you been able to recreate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Is this form in an iframe or something?